# Laravel : Get Related Child Records From A variable containing Found Records

Tags: laravel, eloquent, controller

I am trying to set up some filter options: one is for contact name which will operate on contact table / and other filter for date range which will operate on `Sale` table (`created_at` column).

After I store request inputs into variables I do this:

```
$contacts = Contact::where('first_name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')
                            ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')->get();
```

Then I search for `Sale` records inside date range like this:

```
$sales = Sale::whereBetween('created_at', [$fromDate, $toDate])->get();
```

Then I have this:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
  $data[] = [
     'contact' => $contact->first_name . " " . $contact->last_name,
     'sale' => $contact->sales->sum('amount_spend'),
     'people'=>$contact->sales->sum('people_with')
   ];
 }
dd($data);
```

What I want is for each contact on `$contacts` to find the sum of related `sale::amount_spend`, but I want it to look for related sale records inside `$sales` variable (found set) and not all the table.

Any help appriciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $data = Contact::with([
        'sales'=> function ($query) use($fromDate, $toDate){
            $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$fromDate, $toDate]);
        }])
        ->where('first_name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')
        ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')
        ->get()
        ->map(function($item){
            return [
                'contact' => $item->first_name . " " . $item->last_name,
                'sale' => $item->sales->sum('amount_spend'),
                'people'=>$item->sales->sum('people_with')
            ];
        });
```